# Python trouble with looping through dictionary and replacing xml attribute

Tags: python, xml, loops, dictionary

I am having trouble looping through Python list below and replacing xml attribute with all **ADSType** values.

**Python Dictionary**

```
{'ADSType': ['HS11N', 'HS11V'], 'Type': ['Bond', 'Cash']}
```

**XML**

I'd like to replace **sid** values on each line in XML with ADS values.

```
<req Times="1" action="get" chunklimit="1000" lang="ENU" msg="1" rank="1" rnklst="1" runuf="0">
<flds>
        <f end="2016-02-29" freq="m" i="bond(long) hff" sid="abc" start="2016-02-29" />
        <f end="2016-02-29" freq="m" i="bond(short) ggg" sid="abc" start="2016-02-29" />
</flds>
<dat>
        <r CalculationType="3" ForceCalculate="1" i="123" />
</dat>
</req>
```

**Python Code so far:**

```
data_list = {'ADSType': ['HS11N', 'HS11V'], 'Type': ['Bond', 'Cash']}

xml_file = './test.xml'
tree1 = ET.ElementTree(file=xml_file)
root1 = tree1.getroot()

for x in root1.iter('flds'):
    for y in x.iter('f'):
        y.set('sid', y.get('sid').replace("123", "abc"))
# print(ET.tostring(root1).decode("UTF-8"))
    print "test"
# print(ET.tostring(root1).decode("UTF-8"))
tree1.write("./test.xml")
```

I am stuck how to iterate over list, extract values, feed in replace method dynamically and update xml. Please help! Following is the desired output I am trying to achieve.

```
<req Times="1" action="get" chunklimit="1000" lang="ENU" msg="1" rank="1" rnklst="1" runuf="0">
<flds>
        <f end="2016-02-29" freq="m" i="bond(long) hff" sid="HS11N" start="2016-02-29" />
        <f end="2016-02-29" freq="m" i="bond(short) ggg" sid="HS11V" start="2016-02-29" />
</flds>
<dat>
        <r CalculationType="3" ForceCalculate="1" i="123" />
</dat>
</req>
```

Comment: Why are Bond and Cash there? And how does the dict fit into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to replace anything, just use *set* with the new value which will overwrite:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
xml_file = "./test.xml"

tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root1 = tree.getroot()
data_list = {'ADSType':['HS11N', 'HS11V'], 'Type': ['Bond', 'Cash']}

# make iterator so we just call next(sids) to pull each value
sids = iter(data_list['ADSType'])

for flds in root1.iter('flds'):
    for f in flds.iter('f'):
        # set to new value
        f.set("sid", next(sids))
# write
tree.write("./test.xml")
```

That does exactly what you want although I am not sure how the full dict fits into your question:

test.xml:

```
In [3]: !cat test.xml
<req Times="1" action="get" chunklimit="1000" lang="ENU" msg="1" rank="1" rnklst="1" runuf="0">
    <flds>
        <f end="2016-02-29" freq="m" i="bond(long) hff" sid="abc" start="2016-02-29" />
        <f end="2016-02-29" freq="m" i="bond(short) ggg" sid="abc" start="2016-02-29" />
    </flds>
    <dat>
        <r CalculationType="3" ForceCalculate="1" i="123" />
    </dat>
</req>
```

Run the code:

```
In [4]: from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

In [5]: xml_file = "./test.xml"

In [6]: tree = ET.parse(xml_file)

In [7]: root1 = tree.getroot()

In [8]: data_list = {'ADSType': iter(['HS11N', 'HS11V']), 'Type': iter(['Bond', 'Cash'])}

In [9]: sids = iter(data_list['ADSType'])

In [10]: for flds in root1.iter('flds'):
   ....:     for f in x.iter('f'):
   ....:              f.set("sid", next(sids))
   ....: tree.write("./test.xml")
   ....:
```

New test.xml:

```
In [11]: !cat test.xml
<req Times="1" action="get" chunklimit="1000" lang="ENU" msg="1" rank="1" rnklst="1" runuf="0">
    <flds>
        <f end="2016-02-29" freq="m" i="bond(long) hff" sid="HS11N" start="2016-02-29" />
        <f end="2016-02-29" freq="m" i="bond(short) ggg" sid="HS11V" start="2016-02-29" />
    </flds>
    <dat>
        <r CalculationType="3" ForceCalculate="1" i="123" />
    </dat>
</req>
```

If you have multiple f's inside multiple fld's and want to cycle the values, use *itertools.cycle* in place of iter:

```
from itertools import cycle
sids = cycle(data_list['ADSType'])
```

Comment: Thank you! The solution works! I just wanted to understand this problem. However, currently the data_list is being returned dynamically from another function in a list ['HS11N', 'HS11V']. I want to iterate over the list and update xml.

Comment: So you have a list not a dict?

Comment: Well the logic should be the same, just do `sids  = iter(the_list)` and apply the same logic, if there are multiple and you want to keep cycling use the *itertools.cycle*  logic in the end of the answer.

Comment: Yup exactly. This helps tons! Thanks so much!

Answer (score -2):

This is a quick and dirty way of doing it.

```
for x in root1.iter('flds'):
    f = x.iter('f')
    for idx,y in enumerate(x):
        if y < len(f):
            y.set('sid', y.get('sid').replace("abc",data_list['ADSType'][y]))
```

Simply use enumerate to get the index of f within XML. This is then used for the index within the data_list ADSType.

Not added any verification of XML to make sure the attribute to replace exists. Nor have I took into consideration multiple 'flds' tags. Writing on a tablet so awkward to add more robust code. I'll try and update with something less quick and dirty when back at laptop

Comment: I definitely respect your effort but this doesn't help me learn.